# Trapping Errors In External Applications From VB

Tags: vb.net

We have a VB application which allows the user to, for example, open a Word doc or Excel spreadsheet.  Some of these files are read only, as set by our client, and if saved the user is prompted for a new file name.  In our application if the user chooses to save the 'new' file we need to be able to capture this to perform a save function to add new records to a table in our database.  I don't know if this is possible but when VB opens an external file can it create some sort of wrapper around it so it can capture save button clicks or errors generated from it?  Wishful thinking..  Or is there another way of approaching this that I cannot see..

I forgot to say that we don't really know what type of document the client has put in the folder..

Hope this makes sense and I am not wasting your time.

Kind regards,

Derek.

Comment: I guess we can only do this with Word and Excel as we can create objects but not sure if they open a JPG or a text file in notepad or the e like..

Comment: Don't think you will be able to do this

Comment: I was thinking that..